# Javascript speechSynthesis not working on iOS 12

Tags: javascript, ios, ios12

I am working with JavaScript speechSynthesis API. However, I found that it does not work properly in iOS 12. The `speechSynthesis.speak` only works when the `SpeechSynthesisUtterance.lang` is English. All other languages will result in no voice speech out.

```js
const synth = window.speechSynthesis;
const utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("");
let jpVoice = null;
let enVoice = null;

function loadVoice() {
  const voices = synth.getVoices();
  jpVoice = R.filter(function(target) {
    return target.lang === "ja-JP";
  }, voices)[0];
  enVoice = R.filter(function(target) {
    return target.lang === "en-US";
  }, voices)[0];
}
if ("onvoiceschanged" in speechSynthesis) {
  window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = loadVoice;
} else {
  loadVoice();
}

const speak = () => {
  utterThis.text = "こんにちは、世界！";
  utterThis.lang = "ja-JP";
  utterThis.voice = jpVoice;
  synth.speak(utterThis);
};

const speakWork = () => {
  utterThis.text = "Hello, World!";
  utterThis.lang = "en-US";
  utterThis.voice = enVoice;
  synth.speak(utterThis);
};

const btn = document.getElementById("speak");
const btnWork = document.getElementById("speak-work");

btn.onclick = speak;
btnWork.onclick = speakWork;
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ramda@latest/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>

<body>

 <button id="speak">This work not on ios 12</button><br/>
 <button id="speak-work">This work on ios 12</button>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/lpyk1jjpv9

Please help!!

Comment: Haven't tested, but... can you just confirm your iOS 12 device has some Japanese voices loaded?

Comment: Yes, when `console.log(speechSynthesis.getVoices())`, there is a list of voice including Japanese voices and other languages. You can click [this](https://lpyk1jjpv9.codesandbox.io/) in a iOS 12 device.